# Выпадающее меню при наведении

Tags: html, css

Есть горизонтальное меню, как можно поправить, чтобы при наведении было выпадающее меню?

```css
.menu {
  background: #444;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
}

.menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
  height: 40px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="/users/">Пользователи</a></li>
    <li><a href="/editor/">Редактор</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/punct_1/">Пункт 1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="/testing/">Тестирование</a></li>
    <li><a href="/results/">Результаты</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://html5book.ru/adaptivnoe-vypadayushhee-mega-menyu-na-css/

Comment: У вас не корректная структура html, sub ul должен быть расположен в li.

Comment: @Leks, почему не в ответ? (воспроизводимый пример только сделайте, а не просто ссылка)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
/* Style The Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp